# What is the best way to clean up threading._timer threads in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading

So I have these two classes which I use to schedule a function into a timer.
They work just fine, but they are going to be run in a program for very long durations so I want to be sure I am cleaning up the threads which are "stopped"
correctly.

Can someone please help explain how I would clean up these threads from threading._Timer since I use the setDaemon(True) flag.

How I will be using these classes:
I will create an Object of class Manager, and continue to call MyClassManager.add_oneTimeOperation(MyFunction, 5) over and over...

Thanks!

```
class Operation(threading._Timer):
    alive = True

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        threading._Timer.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.setDaemon(True)

    def run(self):
        while (self.alive):
            self.finished.clear()
            self.finished.wait(self.interval)
            if not self.finished.isSet():
                self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
            else:
                return
            #self.finished.set()

    def run_once(self):
        self.finished.clear()
        self.finished.wait(self.interval)
        if not self.finished.isSet():
            self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
        else:
            return
        self.finished.set()

    def cancel(self):
        self.finished.set()
        self.alive = False

class Manager(object):

    ops = []

    def add_operation(self, operation, interval, args=[], kwargs={}):
        op = Operation(interval, operation, args, kwargs)
        self.ops.append(op)
        thread.start_new_thread(op.run, ())

    def add_oneTimeOperation(self, operation, interval, args=[], kwargs={}):
        op = Operation(interval, operation, args, kwargs)
        self.ops.append(op)
        thread.start_new_thread(op.run_once, ())

    def stop(self):
        for op in self.ops:
            op.cancel()

    def clear_operations(self):
        del self.ops[:]
```

Comment: You shouldn't call `self.finished.clear()` in `run()`; this creates a race condition.  What if the event gets set right before that line runs?  In general, clearing events is rarely a Good Idea unless you're certain nobody else is currently trying to set them, which is typically difficult to ensure.

Comment: True, you are right. However the only place I call finished.set() is at the end of run_once() which shouldn't be a problem, and in cancel(), which wouldn't get called at the same time as run(). So I think I am ok in that regard. Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: What is the point of `cancel()` if you never call it while the thread is running?

Comment: I see what you are saying now. I will go give that a try thank you!